# How to clear a nested array in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, collections, updates

I use the MongoDB C# driver and I want to know how to clear a nested array in MongoDB by using an update query.

Here is my collection containing some documents following the below "schema":

```
{
   "_id": { "$oid": "543cd94799c3ff7a2850a1b6" },
   "Type": 1,
   "Information": [
     {
       "Type" : 2,
       "Colors": [],
       "Heights": [],
       "Widths": []
     }
   ]
}
```

What I want is to clear (remove all elements) the Colors, Heights and Widths nested arrays.

I have tried something like:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.Exists(Entity.INFORMATION + "." + Information.COLORS),
                      Query.Exists(Entity.INFORMATION + "." + Information.HEIGHTS),
                      Query.Exists(Entity.INFORMATION + "." + Information.WIDTHS), 
                      Query.EQ(Entity.TYPE, typeId),
                      Query.ElemMatch(Entity.INFORMATION, Query.EQ(Information.TYPE, informationTypeId)));

var update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Set(Entity.INFORMATION + ".$." + Information.WIDTHS, new BsonArray(new Width[0]))
                                           .Set(Entity.INFORMATION + ".$." + Information.COLORS, new BsonArray(new Color[0]))
                                           .Set(Entity.INFORMATION + ".$." + Information.HEIGHTS, new BsonArray(new Height[0]))
                                           .Set(Entity.INFORMATION + ".$." + Information.TYPE, BsonNull.Value);

Collection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

But it seems that is not working.

Please help.

---

I've tried the following native query but it seems that is not working:

```
db.myCollection.update(
{
  "Information.Colors": {
    $exists: true
  },
  "Type": 1
},
{
  $set: {
    "Information.$.Colors": [],
    "Information.$.Widths": [],
    "Information.$.Heights": [],
    "Information.$.Type" : null
 }
},
false, true)
```

It works only with the first document in the collection.

The rest are remain unaffected... :(

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible to use the positional operator to update all documents in an array.

See: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Answer (score 2):

$ is necessary for nested array, and find query with access to updating field also necessary

```
        var update = Update
            .Set("Information.$.Heights", new BsonArray(new int[0]))
            .Set("Information.$.Colors", new BsonArray(new int[0]))
            .Set("Information.$.Widths", new BsonArray(new int[0]));

        var q = Query.Exists("Information.Heights"); // important

        c.Update(q, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

Comment: The creation of the update variable is correct? Some people use "Information.$.Colors" etc.. What is the difference?

Comment: "Information" is not a json object but a json array. I think it is more tricky when it is an array nested in another array. Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems that is working but it affects only a single document in the collection. The rest of the documents are not affected. Also, I use the UpdateFlags.Multi exactly as the above paradigm.

Comment: I have updated the code I use in the post. But, I really cannot update all documents in the collection. Only the first one is updated.